# nest a join on a field not displayed into this query with a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current Query:

```
Select Name, Charge_code, Charge, Max(Mod)Mod, Max(date)Date
From Table1
Where Name is not Null and Name <>'' and Charge is not Null and charge_code is not null
Group by Name, Charge_Code, Charge
```

In this same table1 I also have a Name identifier Number titled "IDNum" and in a separate table (table2) I also have that same Identifier number "IDNum" with a LocationID in a separate Column in table 2. In table 3 I have that location ID attached to an actual location name "location_Name". This is what I would like to have joined on to my data set.

Ultimately I'm wanting to return the following Results:

Name | Location | Charge Code | Charge | Mod | Date

How can I Nest a join into my existing query to pull back the Location Name based on that Identifier Number but not have the identifier number displayed in the results? sorry if this is a easy question I am new. 
Thanks

tried this to no avail:

```
Select Name, Charge_code, Charge, Max(Mod)Mod, Max(date)Date, Location_Name
 From Table1
Join Location table1.IDNum = Table2.IDNum = Table3.Location_Name
Where Name is not Null and Name <>'' and Charge is not Null and charge_code is not null
Group by Name, Charge_Code, Charge
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` does what you want.

Comment: This is what I tried and its not going. I know I'm doing this wrong not too sure how to set up the join correctly 
    Select Name, Charge_code, Charge, Max(Mod)Mod, Max(date)Date, Location
    From Table1
    Join Location table1.IDNum = Table2.IDNum
    Where Name is not Null and Name <>'' and Charge is not Null and charge_code is not null
    Group by Name, Charge_Code, Charge

Comment: u forgot to put `ON` after `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join 2 tables, then you need to Join it twice with Table 2 is connected to Table 1, and Table 3 is connected to Table 2. This way, you could get the data in Table 3

```
Select Name, Table3.Location_Name as Location,
       Charge_code as 'Charge Code', Charge, 
       Max(Mod) as Mod, Max(date) as Date
From Table1
     Left Join Table2 on Table1.IDNum = Table2.IDNum
     Left Join Table3 on Table2.LocationID = Table3.LocationID 
Where Name is not Null and Name <>'' and Charge is not Null and charge_code is not null
Group by Name, Charge_Code, Charge
```

In [here](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2009/03/12/sql-server-joins-and-types/) you could learn more about `JOIN`. Then you can decide which `JOIN` that suits the most for your case